# Can I use a TP4056 Micro USB 5V 1A instead of a powerboost 1000c to a Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: power-supply, pi-zero, usb-power, retropie, adafruit

I am using a Raspberry Pi Zero and to make it rechargeable I need a Powerboost 1000c (from https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465) would I be able to supplement this for a TP4056 Micro USB 5V 1A?
This is for the simplyRetro Z5 from https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3671784.
Thank you,
Domford

Comment: what's a Powerboost 1000c?

Comment: @jsotola https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465

Comment: Please add the link to your question: [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/116541/edit).